# Regex to separate hexcode

Tags: java, regex

I have a `String` like:

```
String s = "IPhone 5s &#x0024;400"
```

Which I want to get as:

```
String s1 = "IPhone 5s";

String s2 = "$400";
```

What I tried was getting the last word of the `String` and checking if it starts with `"&#"` and if yes, take it out of the `String` and make it UTF-8.

But it might be possible that the Price may not be at the end of the `String`.

Also, does all the currency symbols start with `"$#"`?

Comment: Use grouping to catch the string between `&#` and `;`.

Comment: "does all the currency symbols start with "$#"?" -- that depends on how the string is encoded. The weird thing is, this seems XML or HTML, where plain ASCII characters such as `$` do not *need* to be encoded.

Comment: We can not answer the last question, you have to tell us where this `String` comes from and what it's format is. If you don't know, you first need to figure that out, before doing some regex...

Comment: @brimborium It is a parsed string from XML

Comment: @Jongware Not all of the currency symbols are within the ASCII set, therefore it would be actually nice to have all currency symbols encoded so they are easier to detect.

Comment: @brimborium: true, but surely there could be *other* non-ASCII characters in the string as well, so one still needs to check 'everything'.

Comment: @Jongware Correct. As long as OP doesn't completely specifies the format, we can only guess. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Split before `&#`:

```
String s = "IPhone 5s &#x0024;400"
String[] splitArray = subjectString.split("(?=&#)");
```

After that, call [`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29) on the strings in that array to correctly decode the symbols. If there is only one such symbol (as in your case):

```
splitArray[1] = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(splitArray[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `StringEscapeUtils` or the standard libs with regex, then split the string.

```
import java.io.*;

class Test{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      String p = new String("IPhone 5s &#x0024;400");
      String r = p.replaceAll("(&#x0024;)","\\|\\$");

      String[] s = r.split("\\|"); 
      System.out.println(s[0]);    // IPhone 5s
      System.out.println(s[1]);    // $400
   }
}
```

Example:

**http://ideone.com/epttX4**